# Oracle Database Error - ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted (file # 17, block # 955795)

Tags: oracle, oracle-21c

I have a big table with more than one hundred million records, it has this schema.

schema of the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE USER_B.BIG_TABLE
   (
   field1 NUMBER (10),
   field2 NUMBER(19,0),
   field3 NUMBER(5,0),
   field4 NUMBER(25,0),
   field5 VARCHAR2(55 BYTE),
   field6 NUMBER(10,0),
   field7 VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
   field8 NUMBER(5,0),
   field9 DATE,
   field10 NUMBER(5,0),
   field11 NUMBER(15,0),
   field12 NUMBER(10,0),
   field13 VARCHAR2(55 BYTE),
   field14 NUMBER(20,0),
   field15 NUMBER(10,0),
   field16 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
   field17 NUMBER(10,0),
   field18 NUMBER(5,0),
   field19 NUMBER(15,0),
   field20 NUMBER(15,0)
    ) PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
   NOCOMPRESS 
  STORAGE(
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE "XXXX" 
     PARTITION BY RANGE ("PARTITION_KEY") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')) 
     (PARTITION "SYS_P17408"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2020-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))   NO INMEMORY SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
     PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
     NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
      STORAGE(
     BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
     TABLESPACE "XXXX" );
```

I want to get sample of the above table with the following query.When I run this query I receive data block corrupted error.

```
  insert into /*+parallel(2)*/ SAMPLE_table (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12, field13,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field19,field20)
   (select field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field19,field20 from user_b.big_table where field7 in (select field7 from user_b.big_table group by field7 having count(0)>50) or field13 in (select field13 from user_b.big_table group by field13 having count(0)>100));
   commit;
```

Error is here:

```
   Error report -
   ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted (file # 17, block # 955795)
   ORA-01110: data file 17: '/u01/app/oradata/SIS_Name/dsltbs12.dbf'
```

Also, I run select count(0) from big_table the same error accured.

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: There is a physical corruption of the data file. You'll need your DBA to perform a block recovery from backup to resolve the error. This is not something you can solve with code.

Comment: @pmdba, thank you for your feedback. Would you please explain a little more about block recovery? Do you mean drop table and insert it again or not?

Comment: No. I mean physical recovery of the datafile from a backup, because the *file* is corrupted at least in part. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-01578/  for more info or here https://blog.yannickjaquier.com/oracle/resolve-ora-01578-backup-no-backup.html for possible solutions. Understand that the root cause may be a *hardware* issue, not software.